# WPF Custom Base Window Class and Style

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, resourcedictionary

I have a an app that will open many windows, and I want all windows to look the same.  I am overriding the default Windows window chrome style and making my own, so any new window that is opened (excluding messageboxes) should have the same window style.  However, no matter what I seem to try it does not work.  I can get it to work with one window, but when I want to make it a global style it always crashes or simply doesn't work as it should.

Here is my code:

**WindowBaseStyle.xaml**

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProject.Styles"
                    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:Myproject.Views">
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="GlobalStyles.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type views:WindowBase}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Window}}">
        <Setter Property="AllowsTransparency" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
        <Setter Property="WindowState" Value="Normal" />
        <Setter Property="WindowStyle" Value="SingleBorderWindow" />
        <Setter Property="WindowChrome.WindowChrome">
            <Setter.Value>
                <WindowChrome CaptionHeight="30"
                              UseAeroCaptionButtons="False"/>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type views:WindowBase}">
                    <Border BorderBrush="Blue" BorderThickness="1" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    <DockPanel Background="White" LastChildFill="True" >
                        <Grid Background="Blue" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
                            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                <Button Name="PART_SystemMenuButton" Command="{Binding MenuCommand}" Style="{DynamicResource SystemIconButton}">
                                    <Image Height="16" Width="16" Source="/Resources/icon.png" Stretch="Fill"/>
                                </Button>
                                <Viewbox Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="14,2,0,0" >
                                    <TextBlock FontSize="12" Foreground="White" Text="{Binding Title,RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType=Window}}" />
                                </Viewbox>
                            </StackPanel>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True">
                                    <Button x:Name="PART_MinimizeButton" Command="{Binding MinimizeCommand}" Height="30" Margin="0,0,0,0" ToolTip="Minimize" Width="45">
                                        <Image Source="/Resources/minimize.png" Stretch="None" />
                                        <Button.Style>
                                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#0079CB" />
                                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                                    <Setter.Value>
                                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                                            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                                                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                                            </Border>
                                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                                    </Setter.Value>
                                                </Setter>
                                                <Style.Triggers>
                                                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#64AEEC"/>
                                                    </Trigger>
                                                </Style.Triggers>
                                            </Style>
                                        </Button.Style>
                                    </Button>
                                    <Button x:Name="PART_MaximizeButton" Command="{Binding MaximizeCommand}" Height="30" Margin="0,0,0,0" Width="45">
                                        <Image>
                                            <Image.Style>
                                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=WindowState}" Value="Normal">
                                                            <Setter Property="Source" Value="/Resources/maximize.png" />
                                                            <Setter Property="Stretch" Value="None" />
                                                        </DataTrigger>
                                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=WindowState}" Value="Maximized">
                                                            <Setter Property="Source" Value="/Resources/unmaximize.png" />
                                                            <Setter Property="Stretch" Value="None" />
                                                        </DataTrigger>
                                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                                </Style>
                                            </Image.Style>
                                        </Image>
                                        <Button.Style>
                                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#0079CB" />
                                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                                    <Setter.Value>
                                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                                            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                                                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                                            </Border>
                                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                                    </Setter.Value>
                                                </Setter>
                                                <Style.Triggers>
                                                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#64AEEC"/>
                                                    </Trigger>
                                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=WindowState}" Value="Normal">
                                                        <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="Maximize" />
                                                    </DataTrigger>
                                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=WindowState}" Value="Maximized">
                                                        <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="Restore Down" />
                                                    </DataTrigger>
                                                </Style.Triggers>
                                            </Style>
                                        </Button.Style>
                                    </Button>
                                    <Button x:Name="PART_CloseButton" Command="{Binding CloseCommand}" Height="30" Margin="0,0,0,0" ToolTip="Close" Width="45" >
                                        <Image Source="/Resources/close.png" Stretch="None" />
                                        <Button.Style>
                                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#0079CB" />
                                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                                    <Setter.Value>
                                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                                            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                                                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                                            </Border>
                                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                                    </Setter.Value>
                                                </Setter>
                                                <Style.Triggers>
                                                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                                                    </Trigger>
                                                </Style.Triggers>
                                            </Style>
                                        </Button.Style>
                                    </Button>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                        <!-- this ContentPresenter automatically binds to the content of the window -->
                        <ContentPresenter />
                    </DockPanel>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**WindowBase.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Interop;

namespace MyProject.Views
{
    [TemplatePart(Name = "PART_MinimizeButton", Type = typeof(Button))]
    [TemplatePart(Name = "PART_MaximizeButton", Type = typeof(Button))]
    [TemplatePart(Name = "PART_CloseButton", Type = typeof(Button))]
    [TemplatePart(Name = "PART_SystemMenuButton", Type = typeof(Button))]
    public class WindowBase: Window
    {
        static WindowBase()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(CustomWindow), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(CustomWindow)));
        }

        public WindowBase()
        {
            Loaded += (sender, evnt) =>
            {
                var MinimizeButton = (Button)Template.FindName("PART_MinimizeButton", this);
                var MaximizeButton = (Button)Template.FindName("PART_MaximizeButton", this);
                var CloseButton = (Button)Template.FindName("PART_CloseButton", this);
                var SystemMenuButton = (Button)Template.FindName("PART_SystemMenuButton", this);

                MinimizeButton.Click += (s, e) => WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
                MaximizeButton.Click += (s, e) => WindowState = WindowState == WindowState.Maximized ? WindowState.Normal : WindowState.Maximized;
                CloseButton.Click += (s, e) => Close();
                SystemMenuButton.Click += (s, e) => SystemCommands.ShowSystemMenu(this, GetMousePosition());
            };
        }
    }
}
```

**Window1.xaml**

```
<local:WindowBase x:Class="MyProject.Views.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProject.Views"
        Height="750"
        Width="1125">
    <Grid>
    </Grid>
</local:WindowBase>
```

**Window1.xaml.cs**

```
using System.Windows;

namespace MyProject.Views
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Window1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Window1: WindowBase
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

I am overall following the MVVM pattern, and for the most part from all the articles and videos I have looked at online, they all follow this basic approach and they say it all works, but I can't seem to get it to work.

An additional note is that whenever I add my custom window control to the Window1.xaml file, it breaks the designer and says it is "Invalid Markup"

Also note I added my "WindowBaseStyle" resource dictionary to the App.xaml file as a merged resource dictionary.

Any help is greatly appreciated!!  Thanks

Comment: What's the error when the app crashes, or what's not working? Also, when you say you're going to open many windows but you want them all to look the same, do you anticipate changing anything in the window chrome besides the title? I ask this because the app I work on has a single window class which is reused and has content injected into it via a service. Personally, I'd go that route instead of newing up subclasses of WindowBase.

Comment: @Guttsy The errors differ but mainly consist of namespace issues.  The many windows I am talking about would be for example having a menu on top of the main window, and when a user clicks a menu option a dialog window opens with the content of that particular window.  Currently I am injecting viewmodel instances via "WindowService" class, but I couldn't figure out how one view could have two viewmodels, because the main window has it's own view model, plus the view model of the base window.

Comment: @Guttsy, another approach I saw online that is promising (I started to implement) was create a class library project in the solution and create the "Base" window class there and import it into the WPF project and use it as an imported control.  If you would inject one single window style/base class across the app, how would you do that?  Are you using MVVM?

Comment: We have a homegrown MVVM navigation framework. Prism, etc. were overkill. When you want to display something in a window, the PopupService takes the modal's viewmodel and sets it as the content of a new window. We do viewmodel-first with implicit data templates, but you can override it with a template's key. However, we don't make use of the WPF theme system, so I'm rusty with that external resource style override. Referencing the style directly seems to work, regardless of location. What's your `CustomWindow`? If I remove that and set style manually, it works fine... I think.

Comment: @Guttsy, thanks for the response!  Referencing the style directly in the window control works, but I have custom window buttons (close, maximize, minimize, etc.) and logic for resizing and docking and this code-behind needs to go somewhere other than the style.  There was no way I found to style a window how I want without using the WindowChrome property.  The events needs to be bound to my custom buttons, and since there is a viewmodel for every window instance, there also needs to be a view model for the specific screen itself.  I don't know how to implement that.

Comment: The common window control would not need to have a viewmodel; code-behind is fine for handling minimize, maximize, etc., although you may wish to have some plumbing to make intercepting the close action MVVM-friendly. Your window's style/template will have a `ContentPresenter` in it that's bound to `Content`; `Content` is set by your service when creating the new window. I can whip up an example when I get home from work, but I'll end up making assumptions about how you're handling navigation and getting views up on the screen.

Comment: @Guttsy that would be awesome!  Coders helping out coders, that's why I love stackoverflow :)

Comment: @Jman do you have some code to post that shows how you were intending on getting these windows opened and populated with viewmodels or whatever? Just so I know I'm on the right track?

Comment: In a "WindowService" class and using Ninject, I create a "Kernel" object from Ninject `public IKernel Kernel { private get; set; }`  Then in my App.xaml.cs file: `var kernel = new StandardKernel(); kernel.Load(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()); var windowService = kernel.Get<IWindowService>();  ((WindowService)windowService).Kernel = kernel; windowService.OpenMainWindow();`  The rest of the viewmodels are binding the datacontext in the WindowService class: `var window = new MainWindow(); window.DataContext = Kernel.Get<MainWindowViewModel>(); window.ShowDialog();`

Comment: The "WindowService" class is a class I defined inheriting from an "IWindowService" interface with methods such as "OpenMainWindow()", "OpenDetailsWindow()", "OpenQuestionsWindow()", and so on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, as we discussed in the comments, it seems like the fastest solution to the problem you described is to use a `StaticResource` to get the window's style from a resource dictionary (or create an implicit style for windows.) I questioned the role of `CustomWindow` because I thought that might be causing problems with your default style override. (Remember: if you go the lookless control route and try to use the `DefaultStyleKeyProperty` override, you have to do this on every subclass of that control.)

However, I think doing something like this will get you reusable plumbing for multiple windows driven by viewmodels...

## PopupHost

A class that would derive from your customized window. This code provides the following behaviors:

1. Allows the viewmodel to mark itself as having served its purpose, causing the window to close.
2. Allows attached properties to be specified by individual views that can affect the way the window appears on-screen, e.g. the window title.
3. Can be extended to notify presented items that the user has tried closing the window, allowing interception/cancellation or cleanup actions to be performed.

Code:

```
public class PopupHost : Window
{
    private readonly AwaitableViewModelBase _viewModel;

    public PopupHost(Window owner, AwaitableViewModelBase viewModel, string dataTemplateKey = null)
    {
        Owner = owner;
        _viewModel = viewModel;

        // Wrap the content in another presenter -- makes it a little easier to get to in order to look for attached properties.
        var contentPresenter = new ContentPresenter
        {
            Content = viewModel
        };

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dataTemplateKey))
            contentPresenter.ContentTemplate = (DataTemplate) FindResource(dataTemplateKey);

        Content = contentPresenter;

        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            await viewModel.Task;
            Dispatcher.Invoke(Close);
        });

        Closed += ClosedHandler;

        ApplyTemplate();

        // Grab attached property values from the user control (or whatever element... you just need to find the descendant)
        var contentElement = FindDescendantWithNonDefaultPropertyValue(contentPresenter, PopupWindowProperties.TitleProperty);
        if (contentElement != null)
        {
            var binding = new Binding { Source = contentElement, Path = new PropertyPath(PopupWindowProperties.TitleProperty) };
            SetBinding(TitleProperty, binding);
        }
    }

    private void ClosedHandler(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        _viewModel?.Cancel();
        Closed -= ClosedHandler;
    }

    private static Visual FindDescendant(Visual element, Predicate<Visual> predicate)
    {
        if (element == null)
            return null;

        if (predicate(element))
            return element;

        Visual foundElement = null;
        (element as FrameworkElement)?.ApplyTemplate();

        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(element); i++)
        {
            var visual = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(element, i) as Visual;
            foundElement = FindDescendant(visual, predicate);
            if (foundElement != null)
                break;
        }

        return foundElement;
    }

    private static Visual FindDescendantWithNonDefaultPropertyValue(Visual element, DependencyProperty dp)
    {
        return FindDescendant(element, e => !(dp.GetMetadata(e).DefaultValue ?? new object()).Equals(e.GetValue(dp)));
    }
}
```

## PopupWindowProperties

Just a dumb object containing solely attached properties so your views can convey some information to the window.

```
public static class PopupWindowProperties
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TitleProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Title", typeof(string), typeof(PopupWindowProperties), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(string.Empty));

    public static void SetTitle(UIElement element, string value) => element.SetValue(TitleProperty, value);

    public static string GetTitle(UIElement element) => element.GetValue(TitleProperty) as string;
}
```

## AwaitableViewModelBase

A simple abstract viewmodel which has a `TaskCompletionSource`. This allows the popup window and the viewmodel to coordinate closing.

```
public abstract class AwaitableViewModelBase : ViewModelBase
{
    protected TaskCompletionSource<bool> TaskCompletionSource { get; set; }

    public Task<bool> Task => TaskCompletionSource?.Task;

    public void RegisterTaskCompletionSource(TaskCompletionSource<bool> tcs)
    {
        var current = TaskCompletionSource;
        if (current != null && current.Task.Status == TaskStatus.Running)
            throw new InvalidOperationException();

        TaskCompletionSource = tcs;
    }

    public virtual void Cancel() => SetResult(false);

    protected void SetResult(bool result) => TaskCompletionSource?.TrySetResult(result);
}
```

## WindowService

Last but not least, the simple service that can present the requested view and viewmodel. You can use implicit `DataTemplates` for your viewmodels, or provide the specific `x:Key` value of the template you wish to use. Note that the `await` doesn't really do anything here because `ShowDialog` blocks. We return the `bool` since it can be used to easily identify if the user hit `OK` or `Cancel` on a modal.

```
public class WindowService
{
    public async Task<bool> ShowModalAsync(AwaitableViewModelBase viewModel, string dataTemplateKey = null)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
        viewModel.RegisterTaskCompletionSource(tcs);

        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            var currentWindow = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<Window>().SingleOrDefault(x => x.IsActive) ?? Application.Current.MainWindow;
            var window = new PopupHost(currentWindow, viewModel, dataTemplateKey);
            window.ShowDialog();
        });

        return await viewModel.Task;
    }
}
```

Comment: this is awesome!  As soon as I am able to try this I will let you know.  Thanks!